# Find path of an executable in vim

Tags: vim

On some machines I'm using an external executable to format text (it's named 'par').
Therefore I'd like to detect if the executable is installed.

Edit: I just want to detect if the executable is available in my .vimrc itself. So I prefer internal functions over external utils like 'which'. Prince Goulash's solution is already very helpful and I'm going with it, despite I'd prefer finding the exact path. Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the vimscript function `executable()`, which returns 1 if its argument exists and is executable, and 0 otherwise. It doesn't return the path of the file, though. See `help executable` for more info.

Comment: You can also use `exepath()` if you need the _full path_ to the executable, analogous to the `which` utility.

Answer (score 4):

In linux, I'd use [which](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?which):

```
:!which par
```

If you want to put it into the file, try this:

```
:r !which par
```

Edit: Actually, [hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592620/check-if-a-program-exists-from-a-bash-script/677212#677212) might be the better tool to use.

Answer (score 0):

in unix...

```
whereis par
```

should return a path, if it is executable by the current user